# Erro ao criar e baixar XLS com CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, xls

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->autoLayout = false;
    $turmaId = base64_decode($turmaId);
    $turma = $this->Turma->find('first',array(
        'conditions'=>array(
            'Turma.id'=>$turmaId
        ),
        'fields'=>array(
            'Turma.turma','Serie.serie'
        ),
        'recursive'=>0
    ));
    echo 'Alunos do ' . iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE//IGNORE",$turma['Serie']['serie']) . ' - Turma ' . iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE//IGNORE",$turma['Turma']['turma'])."\r\n";
    echo 'Nome'."\t".'Email'."\t".iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE//IGNORE",'Aniversário')."\t".'Data Cadastro'."\r\n";
    $data = $this->Turma->query('SELECT
    CONCAT(Pessoa.primeiro_nome," ",Pessoa.ultimo_nome) AS Nome,
    Pessoa.email,
    DATE_FORMAT(Aluno.created,"%d/%m/%Y") AS DataCadastro,      
    DATE_FORMAT(Pessoa.data_nascimento,"%d/%m/%Y") AS Aniversario       
    FROM alunos AS Aluno
    LEFT JOIN pessoas AS Pessoa
    ON Aluno.pessoa_id = Pessoa.id
    WHERE Aluno.turma_id = '.$turmaId.'
    ORDER BY Nome');
    foreach($data as $data) {
        echo iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE//IGNORE",$data[0]['Nome']);
        echo "\t".$data['Pessoa']['email'];            
        echo "\t".$data[0]['Aniversario'];
        echo "\t".$data[0]['DataCadastro'];
        echo "\r\n";
    }

    $nomeArquivo = Inflector::slug('Alunos '.$turma['Serie']['serie'].' '.$turma['Turma']['turma']);
    $this->response->disableCache();
    $this->response->type('xls'); 
    $this->response->download('teste.xls');
    $this->response->body();       
    $this->response->send();
```

Local está funcionando corretamente ou seja, criar e baixa o XLS com os dados que preciso. Mas ao subir para o servidor, não gera o arquivo e os dados são printados na tela. Alguma solução?

**Edit--**

Resolvi o problema usando o Component PhpExcel, disponível em: https://github.com/segy/PhpExcel

Comment: Qual é o erro gerado?

Comment: Na verdade não gera erro. O que ocorria é que os dados estavam sendo impressos na tela, ao invés de serem gravados no arquivo.